# exec returning 255

Tags: c, unix

I have my code running on the Mac and I am getting a 255 return code from exec.
The following is the code:

```
    ret = execvp(pArgs[0], pArgs);  

    if (ret < 0) 
{
        ret = errno;
        exit(ret);
        return false;
    }
else if (processId < 0) 
{
    // fork() failed    
    return false;
    } 
else if(Wait)
{
    // forked successfuly so wait for exit
    if(waitpid(processId, &childstatus, 0) == processId)
    {
        // codesign command terminted, get return code
        if(WIFEXITED(childstatus))
        {
            if(pCmdRetStatus != NULL)
                *pCmdRetStatus = WEXITSTATUS(childstatus);
        }

    }   
}
```

Any thoughts on why the 255? Essentially an hdiutil call, a lot of times, I get 255.

Comment: What do you get if you put `printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));` after the call to `execvp` (which by the way will always return `-1`, if it returns -- if successful, it does not return).

Comment: What does `perror()` say?  The `execve` man page has a big list of reasons it could fail.

Comment: [`execvp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) != [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[UNIX (and therefore Mac OS X) exit statuses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Unix) are forced into the range 0-255 unsigned.

So a return value of `-1` from your call to `execvp` would be processed as -1 in your C code but would become 255 at the operating-system level due to [the rules of the `exit()` function specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html).  Consider the following example:

```
bash> bash
bash2> exit -1
bash> echo $? # The exit status of the last command (bash2)
255
```

Comment: @reza: sorry if I was being obtuse.  Your call to `execvp` might return a value of -1 which would result in your process exiting with status code 255.  Basically, UNIX operating systems only allow values 0-255 for exit statuses and -1 gets automatically changed to 255.

Comment: `unsigned i = -1` is not 255 (or the max size for the particular implementation) because of 2's complement, but because the C Standard says it has to be.

Comment: @rubenvb: aha, you're right!  Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated my answer.

Comment: A snip of the paged linked in the answer says `though only the least significant 8 bits (that is, status & 0377) shall be available to a waiting parent process.`.  For starters I believe that's octal, which would be 0xFF in hex.  But I was not able to mask it, instead I had to take the modulo: `int converted = status % 0xFF;`  to get a a matching answer

Comment: interesting hhmm

Answer (score 1):

[execvp](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/execvp.3.html) returns an integer (-1) on error (and sets errno, which you should check/print (hint: `perror`)) which you pass to `exit`. Exit really only knows about `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS`, but it generally just passed on the value to the OS (which can usually handle 0-127 / 0-255, but don't count on it).

Answer (score 0):

The only possible return value<strike>s</strike> for `exec` <strike>are 0 and</strike> is -1. I'm guessing the type of the variable `ret` is wrong (`unsigned char` instead of `int`) and thus -1 is getting converted modulo 256 to 255.

Comment: Actually, the only possible return value for `exec` is `-1`: if it succeeds, it does not return.

Comment: Haha of course you're right. That was a pretty stupid mistake of mine.